# How to use Pandas dataframe as map without common index

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that contains mapping information as below:

```
dfMap = pd.DataFrame({'BId': ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Guava', np.nan, np.nan],
                      'NId': [np.nan, 'GOne',  np.nan, 'GFive','GTwo'],
                      'Id': ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Guava', 'GFive', 'GTwo']})
print(dfMap)

      BId    NId      Id
0  Banana    NaN  Banana
1   Apple   GOne   Apple
2   Guava    NaN   Guava
3     NaN  GFive   GFive
4     NaN   GTwo    GTwo
```

And I have a input dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'S': ['Banana', 'GTwo', 'Apple', 'GOne', 'Guava', 'GFive'],
                   'G': ['BI', 'NI', 'BI', 'NI', 'BI', 'NI']})
print(df)

        S   G
0  Banana  BI
1    GTwo  NI
2   Apple  BI
3    GOne  NI
4   Guava  BI
5   GFive  NI
```

Now I want to add new column df['Id'] which is mapped value from dfMap, so output dataframe should be like this:

```
        S   G      Id
0  Banana  BI  Banana
1    GTwo  NI    GTwo
2   Apple  BI   Apple
3    GOne  NI   Apple
4   Guava  BI   Guava
5   GFive  NI   GFive
```

I tried using below code using np.where but it is giving me error:

```
mask = df[df['G'] == 'BI']
df['Id'] = np.where(mask, dfMap.loc[df['S'] == dfMap['BId'], 'Id'], dfMap.loc[df['S'] == dfMap['NId'], 'Id'])

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Any thoughts, hints, info, links would be helpful.

Comment: Something wrong?

Comment: yes, it seems some issue if I have multiple Nan in BId and NId. I am trying to update the question above. Give me sometime.

Comment: I check new data and working nice with my solution.

Comment: I am getting error as "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects". But I guess it can easily be resolved by eliminating the NaN from index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by condition with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) if only `BI` and `NI` values in `G` column:

```
a = dfMap.set_index('BId')['Id']
b = dfMap.set_index('NId')['Id']

mask = df['G'] == 'BI'
df['Id'] = np.where(mask, df['S'].map(a), df['S'].map(b))
print (df)
        S   G      Id
0  Banana  BI  Banana
1    GTwo  NI    GTwo
2   Apple  BI   Apple
3    GOne  NI   Apple
```

Comment: I have updated my above code and dataframe to have multiple NaN in BId and NId. Now when I execute the above code I get error message as: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects.

Comment: I modified the above code as | a = dfMap[dfMap['BId'].notna()].set_index('BId')['Id'] and same for b, then it works. Thanks.